Why a process( which is Markov with recpect to transition operators $\{P_{s,t}\}_{0\le s\le t \le T}$) is a Markov process?
I saw this statement on P77 of Da Prato,    G.,  Zabczyk, J.: Stochastic Equations in Infinite Dimensions. Second edition, Cambridge University Press, Cambridge (2014).
Set a filtrated probability space $(\Omega,{\mathcal F},\{{\mathcal F}_t\},{\mathbb P})$, and
let $H$ be a seperable Hilbert space, with $\mathcal E$ its borel $\sigma$ algebra constructing a measure space $(H,\mathcal E)$.
An ${\mathcal F}_t$-adapeted process $X(t)$, $t\in [0,T]$, valued in $(H,\mathcal E)$ is said to be a Marokov process if:
\begin{equation}
{\mathbb P}(X(t)\in A | {\mathcal F}_s)={\mathbb P}(X(t)\in A | \sigma(X(s)))\quad {\mathbb P}-{\rm a.s}.
\end{equation}
Where $\sigma(X(s))$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra in $\Omega$ generated by $X(s)$.
$B_b(H)$ is the set of bounded and measurable functions $\varphi:H \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$. Equipped with the norm $\|\varphi\|=\displaystyle \sup_{x \in H}|\varphi(x)|$, it is a banach space.
A family of bounded linear operators
$P_{s,t}:B_b(H)\rightarrow B_b(H),0 \le s \le t \le T$, is said to be Markovian if

$P_{s,t}\varphi \ge 0$ for $\varphi\ge0$, for $\varphi\in B_b(H)$, $t\ge s$,

$P_{s,t}1=1$ for $\varphi\ge0$ for $t\ge s$,

$P_{s,t}P_{t,u}=P_{s,u}$ for $s\le t \le u$.


An ${\mathcal F}_t$-adapeted process $X(t)$, $t\in [0,T]$, valued in $(H,\mathcal E)$ is said to be a Marokov with trasition operators $\{P_{s,t}\}_{0\le s\le t \le T}$, if for arbitraty $\varphi \in B_b(H)$ and $0\le s\le t \le T$:
\begin{equation}
{\mathbb E}(\varphi(X(t))| {\mathcal F}_s)=P_{s,t}\varphi(X(s))\quad {\mathbb P}-{\rm a.s}.
\end{equation}
Prato point out that, if a process $X(t)$ is Markov with transition operators $\{P_{s,t}\}_{0\le s\le t \le T}$, it is a Markov process.
$\textbf{My question is:why such statement is true?}$
Assume that $X(t)$ is Markov with transition operators $\{P_{s,t}\}_{0\le s\le t \le T}$, choose $\varphi=1_A$ for $A \in \mathcal E$. Here $1_A$ is the indicator function of $A$. Then we have
\begin{equation}
{\mathbb P}(X(t)\in A | {\mathcal F}_s)={\mathbb E}(1_A(X(t))| {\mathcal F}_s)=P_{s,t}1_A(X(s)) =? \,{\mathbb P}(X(t)\in A | \sigma(X(s)))
\end{equation}
It seems no connection between $P_{s,t}1_A(X(s))$ and ${\mathbb P}(X(t)\in A | \sigma(X(s)))$, so why is such statement true?

More in general, consider $X:(\Omega,\mathscr{F})\to(A,\mathscr{A})$ and $Y:(\Omega,\mathscr{F})\to(B,\mathscr{B})$ and also a sub-$\sigma$-alegbra $\mathscr{G}\subseteq \mathscr{F}$ such that $\sigma(Y)\subseteq \mathscr{G}$ (i.e. $Y$ is $\mathscr{G}$-measurable). Suppose that $P(X\in E|\mathscr{G})=f_E(Y)$ $P$-a.s. for all $E\in \mathscr{A}$, where each $f_E:B\to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable. This also implies that each $f_E(Y):\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable. Let $C\in \mathscr{B}$ be arbitrary. Then
$$E[\mathbf{1}_{\{Y \in C\}}\mathbf{1}_{\{X \in E\}}]=E[\mathbf{1}_{\{Y \in C\}}E[\mathbf{1}_{\{X \in E\}}|\mathscr{G}]]=E[\mathbf{1}_{\{Y \in C\}}f_E(Y)]$$
which implies $P(X \in E|Y)=f_E(Y)=P(X\in E|\mathscr{G})$ $P$-a.s. for all $E \in \mathscr{A}$.

Thanks alot！This problem puzzle me few days.
